# Cannot install rvictl to capture network

Tags: macos, ios, network, xcode, wireshark

I'm trying to route my iphone traffic through my mac to view it with wireshark. However rvictl is not on my machine. I have:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
- El Capitan 10.11.6
- XCode 7.3.1
- XCode command line tools for XCode 7.3.1 (installed separately)

However rvictl is no where on my machine. Any idea how to get it?

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/installer -pkg /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg -target /
```

Comment: `rvictl` was still not being found even after installing `MobileDevice.pkg` and `MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg`. In macOS 10.15.1 (19B88) and Xcode 11.2 (11B52), the location where this executable can be found is `/Library/Apple/usr/bin`.